# In an arithmetic expression, why does incrementing a variable modify the original where other operations do not?

Tags: linux, bash, math, expression

Example:

```
$ number=1
$ (( number++ ))
$ echo $number
2
$ (( number * 10 ))
$ echo $number
2
```

The fix is simple: `number=$(( number * 10 ))`, I just don't understand for what possible reason the two operations behave differently.

Comment: The behavior of the `++` operator is the special case.  It mirrors the behavior of the same operator in C.  In Bash, very few operations directly modify their operands; most only compute a value.  Such operations are generally more convenient to build upon, but the behavior of the `++` operator is wanted often enough to warrant its inclusion as well, alongside the ordinary `+` operator.

Comment: just try `(( number *= 10 ))` and see.  The operators emulate their C counterparts, so you need some C background to know about these.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger - if your comment was an answer, I would have accepted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The fix is simple: `number=$(( number * 10 ))`, […]

The notation you're looking for is

```
(( number *= 10 ))
```

which is a shorthand for

```
(( number = number * 10 ))
```

I think you'll agree that it would be surprising if something like `echo $(( 3 * a + 12 * b ))` suddenly changed the value of `a` or `b`. Changes to variables are therefore always *explicit*: they use one of the operators that are specifically designed for assignment, such as `=` and `+=`. As you've observed, the increment operator `++` is one of these (as is the decrement operator, `--`).

Comment: Wikipedia has the increment operator (foo++) listed under "Arithmetic Operators", but there is an entire table of "Compound assignment operators" which I was mostly unaware of (bar `+=`). `*=` is unsurprisingly referred to as the "Multiplication assignment" operator.

Interesting! Thanks ruakh.

Answer (score 3):

Because that is what they are designed to do.

If you want the value of `number+1` without changing `number`, you use (unsurprisingly) `number+1`.

Comment: Please don't be so rude to new programmers.

Comment: @Cybersupernova Don't mistake bluntness for rudeness.

Answer (score 1):

Its all about `value` and `reference`.

The `++` operator increments the value of memory cell referenced by `$number` while all other (leaving few more like `--`) operators process only the value of `$number`.

Hence `++` increases the value of `$number` while others return calculated value to any variable (`$number` in your case)